# Julia How does the sync and distribute work?

Tags: multithreading, julia, distributed

I'm trying to use multi processing/threading to speed up one-hot-encoding while working with UNet in Julia. If I run this on julia -t 9 -p 4 so 9 threads and 5 procs,
It errors on NaN and thus seems like an out of sync calculation?
This is the code where I calculate weights and then one hot labels

```
using Distributed
labels=[1,2]
pmap(1:target_image_size) do i
    for j = 1:target_image_size
        k = labels_matrix[i, j, 1]
        weights[findfirst(k .== labels)] += 1
    end
end

weights = weights / maximum(weights)
...
Threads.@threads for i = 1:target_image_size
    for j = 1:target_image_size
        k = labels_matrix[i, j, 1]
        label_idx = findfirst(labels .== k)
        onehot_target[i, j, label_idx] = weights[label_idx]  

    end
end
```

so if an target_image_size is 256x256 and it has [1 2 2;2 2 1]
one hot_target should  be [1 0 0;0 0 1] and [0 1 1;1 1 0]
I start Julia as `julia -t 9 -p 4`

So the error is following :

```
Error During Test at model.jl:34
  Got exception outside of a @test
  InexactError: Int64(NaN)
  Stacktrace:
    [1] (::Base.var"#837#839")(x::Task)
      @ Base ./asyncmap.jl:177
    [2] foreach(f::Base.var"#837#839", itr::Vector{Any})
      @ Base ./abstractarray.jl:2141
    [3] maptwice(wrapped_f::Function, chnl::Channel{Any}, worker_tasks::Vector{Any}, c::Vector{Int64})
      @ Base ./asyncmap.jl:177
    [4] wrap_n_exec_twice
      @ ./asyncmap.jl:153 [inlined]
    [5] #async_usemap#822
      @ ./asyncmap.jl:103 [inlined]
    [6] #asyncmap#821
      @ ./asyncmap.jl:81 [inlined]
    [7] asyncmap
      @ ./asyncmap.jl:81 [inlined]
    [8] (::UNet.var"#10#13"{Vector{CloudLocation}, Vector{Int8}, Int64})()
      @ UNet ~/data.jl:73
    [9] in_scratch_dir(func::UNet.var"#10#13"{Vector{CloudLocation}, Vector{Int8}, Int64}, temp::String)
      @ Jaws ~LocalDiskHelpers.jl:106
   [10] in_scratch_dir (repeats 2 times)
      @ ~LocalDiskHelpers.jl:96 [inlined]
   [11] load_target_files
      @ ~data.jl:64 [inlined]
   [12] load_image_and_target_files
      @ ~data.jl:15 [inlined]
   [13] train(train_dataset::ImageDataset, test_dataset::ImageDataset, model::Unet, opt::RMSProp, loss::UNet.var"#loss#62"{typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy), Unet}; batch_size::Int64, test_batch_size::Int64, num_epochs::Int64, learning_rate_drop_rate::Float64, learning_rate_step::Int64, device::Function, save_intermediate_models::Bool, save_model::Bool, out_dir::String, model_file_name::String, save_pred_image::Bool, pred_image_postfix::String, pred_image_ext::String)
      @ UNet ~train.jl:112
   [14] train(train_dataset::ImageDataset, test_dataset::ImageDataset, num_channels::Int64, labels::Vector{Int8}; loss_function::typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy), learning_rate::Float64, momentum::Float64, device::Function, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol, Any, NTuple{7, Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:num_epochs, :batch_size, :test_batch_size, :save_intermediate_models, :save_model, :out_dir, :model_file_name), Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64, Bool, Bool, String, String}}})
      @ UNet ~train.jl:40
   [15] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:36 [inlined]
   [16] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [17] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:36 [inlined]
   [18] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [19] top-level scope
      @ ~model.jl:24
   [20] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [21] top-level scope
      @ ~runtests.jl:47
   [22] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [23] top-level scope
      @ REPL[1]:1
   [24] eval
      @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
   [25] eval_user_input(ast::Any, backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:139
   [26] repl_backend_loop(backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:200
   [27] start_repl_backend(backend::REPL.REPLBackend, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:185
   [28] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any; backend_on_current_task::Bool)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:317
   [29] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:305
   [30] (::Base.var"#874#876"{Bool, Bool, Bool})(REPL::Module)
      @ Base ./client.jl:387
   [31] #invokelatest#2
      @ ./essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
   [32] invokelatest
      @ ./essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
   [33] run_main_repl(interactive::Bool, quiet::Bool, banner::Bool, history_file::Bool, color_set::Bool)
      @ Base ./client.jl:372
   [34] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
      @ Base ./client.jl:302
   [35] _start()
      @ Base ./client.jl:485
┌ Warning: Opening file with JLD2.MmapIO failed, falling back to IOStream
└ @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:233
Testing: Error During Test at model.jl:52
  Got exception outside of a @test
  SystemError: opening file "/tmp/jl_SjrXkR/UNet_demo.jld2": No such file or directory
  Stacktrace:
    [1] systemerror(p::String, errno::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing)
      @ Base ./error.jl:168
    [2] #systemerror#62
      @ ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
    [3] systemerror
      @ ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
    [4] open(fname::String; lock::Bool, read::Bool, write::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, append::Bool)
      @ Base ./iostream.jl:293
    [5] openfile
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:223 [inlined]
    [6] openfile(T::Type, fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, fallback::Type)
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:234
    [7] jldopen(fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, iotype::Type{JLD2.MmapIO}; fallback::Type{IOStream}, compress::Bool, mmaparrays::Bool, typemap::Dict{String, Any})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:290
    [8] jldopen(fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, iotype::Type{JLD2.MmapIO})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:253
    [9] jldopen(fname::String, mode::String; iotype::Type, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:356
   [10] jldopen (repeats 2 times)
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:351 [inlined]
   [11] jldopen(f::Function, args::String; kws::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:2
   [12] jldopen
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:2 [inlined]
   [13] macro expansion
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:145 [inlined]
   [14] load_unet(filename::String)
      @ UNet ~model_IO.jl:33
   [15] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:54 [inlined]
   [16] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [17] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:54 [inlined]
   [18] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [19] top-level scope
      @ ~model.jl:24
   [20] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [21] top-level scope
      @ ~/runtests.jl:47
   [22] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [23] top-level scope
      @ REPL[1]:1
   [24] eval
      @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
   [25] eval_user_input(ast::Any, backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:139
   [26] repl_backend_loop(backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:200
   [27] start_repl_backend(backend::REPL.REPLBackend, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:185
   [28] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any; backend_on_current_task::Bool)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:317
   [29] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:305
   [30] (::Base.var"#874#876"{Bool, Bool, Bool})(REPL::Module)
      @ Base ./client.jl:387
   [31] #invokelatest#2
      @ ./essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
   [32] invokelatest
      @ ./essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
   [33] run_main_repl(interactive::Bool, quiet::Bool, banner::Bool, history_file::Bool, color_set::Bool)
      @ Base ./client.jl:372
   [34] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
      @ Base ./client.jl:302
   [35] _start()
      @ Base ./client.jl:485
  
  caused by: SystemError: opening file "/tmp/jl_SjrXkR/UNet_demo.jld2": No such file or directory
  Stacktrace:
    [1] systemerror(p::String, errno::Int32; extrainfo::Nothing)
      @ Base ./error.jl:168
    [2] #systemerror#62
      @ ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
    [3] systemerror
      @ ./error.jl:167 [inlined]
    [4] open(fname::String; lock::Bool, read::Bool, write::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, append::Bool)
      @ Base ./iostream.jl:293
    [5] JLD2.MmapIO(fname::String, write::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool)
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/mmapio.jl:105
    [6] openfile
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:226 [inlined]
    [7] openfile(T::Type, fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, fallback::Type)
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:231
    [8] jldopen(fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, iotype::Type{JLD2.MmapIO}; fallback::Type{IOStream}, compress::Bool, mmaparrays::Bool, typemap::Dict{String, Any})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:290
    [9] jldopen(fname::String, wr::Bool, create::Bool, truncate::Bool, iotype::Type{JLD2.MmapIO})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:253
   [10] jldopen(fname::String, mode::String; iotype::Type, kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:356
   [11] jldopen (repeats 2 times)
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/JLD2.jl:351 [inlined]
   [12] jldopen(f::Function, args::String; kws::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}})
      @ JLD2 ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:2
   [13] jldopen
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:2 [inlined]
   [14] macro expansion
      @ ~/.julia/packages/JLD2/k9Gt0/src/loadsave.jl:145 [inlined]
   [15] load_unet(filename::String)
      @ UNet ~model_IO.jl:33
   [16] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:54 [inlined]
   [17] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [18] macro expansion
      @ ~model.jl:54 [inlined]
   [19] macro expansion
      @ /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Test/src/Test.jl:1151 [inlined]
   [20] top-level scope
      @ ~model.jl:24
   [21] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [22] top-level scope
      @ ~runtests.jl:47
   [23] include(fname::String)
      @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444
   [24] top-level scope
      @ REPL[1]:1
   [25] eval
      @ ./boot.jl:360 [inlined]
   [26] eval_user_input(ast::Any, backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:139
   [27] repl_backend_loop(backend::REPL.REPLBackend)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:200
   [28] start_repl_backend(backend::REPL.REPLBackend, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:185
   [29] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any; backend_on_current_task::Bool)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:317
   [30] run_repl(repl::REPL.AbstractREPL, consumer::Any)
      @ REPL /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/REPL/src/REPL.jl:305
   [31] (::Base.var"#874#876"{Bool, Bool, Bool})(REPL::Module)
      @ Base ./client.jl:387
   [32] #invokelatest#2
      @ ./essentials.jl:708 [inlined]
   [33] invokelatest
      @ ./essentials.jl:706 [inlined]
   [34] run_main_repl(interactive::Bool, quiet::Bool, banner::Bool, history_file::Bool, color_set::Bool)
      @ Base ./client.jl:372
   [35] exec_options(opts::Base.JLOptions)
      @ Base ./client.jl:302
   [36] _start()
      @ Base ./client.jl:485
```

Comment: The important part of the Stacktrace - about where the error actually originates - has been cut out at the bottom. Can you post the rest of the stacktrace please?

Comment: Also, this seems quite likely to be a data problem rather than anything to do with multiprocessing - can you verify whether the code works without the `@sync @distributed`, or if that also returns the same `InexactError`?

Comment: You are mixing two things. Either you want to do multithreading or multuprocessing. This code would look diffrent in each of those scenarios. In case of multithreading the memory is shared across threads, while in case of multiprocessing each process has its own memory and thus do not see variables from other processes (unless some dedicated mechanism is involved). Perhaps you should make a simple MWE showing what you want to do?

Comment: @SundarR I've just added the error log and create MWE

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I'm not sure I want to test overhead and speed before I decide. I have 16 cores and I'm hoping to use them and speedup a training. These nested for loops are taking a big chunk of time so I'm trying to speed them up in any way possible

Comment: @h612 this is not MWE as is not self-contained example. Please create a very simplified MWE that actually runs and works but is not parallelized. Than we can tell you how to best parallelize it. The error you pasted is related to storing a `Float64` in an `Int` matrix and most likely would be found when writing non-parallelized code.